# How to create a form field from a checkbox group using Angular Material?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, checkboxlist, form-control

I have an Angular component which takes an array of value objects as input and would like to represent the items as checkboxes.

The value objects come from the back-end. The form builder generates the form array in the form group. My question is how can I treat these checkboxes a form field (validation, initial value, etc.)?

I have this in the component:

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

locationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  locationOptions: this.formBuilder.array([this.locations])
});
```

`this.locations` is the input. The HTML code is like this:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content *ngFor="let location of locations">
    <mat-checkbox>{{location.name}}</mat-checkbox>
   </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

How should I modify the HTML part to make this checkbox group as a form field and send the selected items to a back-end later? And would like to add validation to this new form field, and later introduce initially selected items.

Comment: I believe `[this.locations]` is making an array of arrays. Try with `this.formBuilder.array(this.locations)` instead.

Comment: @trichetriche - they're going over location of locations though... So I don't think that'll be their issue.

Comment: @nstanard true that !

Comment: [Material has a guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control) on how to create custom form field controls - have you looked at that to see if that is what you need?

Comment: Yea, I would check the docs and look for examples for sure. There are attributes you can add to the mat-checkbox element that make it do the things you want. Check out the following example: https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/checkbox-implementation-in-angular-using-angular-material/

Comment: The actual documentation on mat-checkbox: https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api

Comment: Thanks for the links!